# Showing "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" while using it in nltk.FreqDist() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to get the frequency distribution of the word in a phrase according to its degree using nltk. It is showing "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" though. Don't understand what the problem is. Please help.

P.S: The code has a whole lot of bugs so don't mind that. I am trying to build a keyword extractor using code snippets from many many programs as I am a noob to python. If anyone wants to shed some light on the other bugs are also welcome.

Code:

```
from __future__ import division
import operator
import nltk
import string

def isPunct(word):
  return len(word) == 1 and word in string.punctuation

def isNumeric(word):
  try:
    float(word) if '.' in word else int(word)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False

class KeyExt:

  def __init__(self):
    self.stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words())
    self.top_fraction = 1

  def _generate_candidate_keywords(self, sentences):
    phrase_list = []
    for sentence in sentences:
      words = map(lambda x: "|" if x in self.stopwords else x, nltk.word_tokenize(sentence.lower()))
      phrase = []
      for word in words:
        if word == "|" or isPunct(word):
          if len(phrase) > 0:
            phrase_list.append(phrase)
            phrase = []
        else:
          phrase.append(word)
    return phrase_list

  def _calculate_word_scores(self, phrase_list):
    word_freq = nltk.FreqDist()
    word_degree = nltk.FreqDist()
    for phrase in phrase_list:
      degree = [x for x in phrase if not isNumeric(x)] 
      for word in phrase:
        word_freq[word]=word_freq[word]+1
        word_degree[word, degree]=word_degree[word, degree]+1 
    for word in word_freq.keys():
      word_degree[word] = word_degree[word] + word_freq[word] 
    word_scores = {}
    for word in word_freq.keys():
      word_scores[word] = word_degree[word] / word_freq[word]
    return word_scores

  def _calculate_phrase_scores(self, phrase_list, word_scores):
    phrase_scores = {}
    for phrase in phrase_list:
      phrase_score = 0
      for word in phrase:
        phrase_score += word_scores[word]
      phrase_scores[" ".join(phrase)] = phrase_score
    return phrase_scores

  def extract(self, text, incl_scores=False):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    phrase_list = self._generate_candidate_keywords(sentences)
    word_scores = self._calculate_word_scores(phrase_list)
    phrase_scores = self._calculate_phrase_scores(phrase_list, word_scores)
    sorted_phrase_scores = sorted(phrase_scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    n_phrases = len(sorted_phrase_scores)
    if incl_scores:
      return sorted_phrase_scores[0:int(n_phrases/self.top_fraction)]
    else:
      return map(lambda x: x[0],
        sorted_phrase_scores[0:int(n_phrases/self.top_fraction)])

def test():
  search=input("Enter Text: ")
  ke = KeyExt()
  keywords = ke.extract(search, incl_scores=True)
  print (keywords)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  test()
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\SAURAV
DAS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\projects\nlpproj.py", line
81, in <module>
    test()   File "C:\Users\SAURAV DAS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\projects\nlpproj.py", line
77, in test
    keywords = ke.extract(search, incl_scores=True)   File "C:\Users\SAURAV
DAS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\projects\nlpproj.py", line
64, in extract
    word_scores = self._calculate_word_scores(phrase_list)   File "C:\Users\SAURAV
DAS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\projects\nlpproj.py", line
44, in _calculate_word_scores
    word_degree[word, degree]=word_degree[word, degree]+1 TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Show the full traceback (with line numbers and the causing line of code)

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suit to see what might be happening.  Also you might want to just print data at strategic locations to help in you debugging effort.

Comment: ok will do so in a sec

Comment: Didn't quite get you @wwii

Comment: Oh ok... You answered me for my debugging question @wwii. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you are trying to use a `list` as a `dict` key. `list`s are not hashable and can't be used for keys (e.g. `tuple`s can be used).

In your case in this line

```
    word_degree[word, degree]=word_degree[word, degree]+1
```

you are using degree as an index for `word_degree` that doesn't make sense cause degree itself is a `list`.

Comment: So can you suggest me a solution

Comment: @IncognitoPossum I just answered what the error is. Please add more details to your question like what is `word_degree` and `degree` and what this line of code should do.

Comment: 'word_degree' gives the degree or priority of a word. At least that's what I want to do. Sorry for the delay in reply though. Was suffering from fever.

Comment: @IncognitoPossum Hope you're better now :) so why don't you do `word_degree[word] += 1`